# How would I filter by type? and another left join correctly?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I would like to filter by transactions deposit type => transactions.type and how would one left join another table in this query?

```
SELECT 
    calendar.datefield AS DATE,
    Ifnull(Sum(transactions.deposit_amount), 0) AS total_deposits,
    transactions.type
FROM transactions
RIGHT JOIN calendar
ON (Date(transactions.created_at) = calendar.datefield)
WHERE      
(
  calendar.datefield BETWEEN
        (
            SELECT Min(Date(created_at))
            FROM   transactions
        )
    AND
        (
             SELECT Max(Date(created_at))
             FROM   transactions
         )
 )
```

Comment: the end of the query should have GROUP BY date

Comment: ok i figured it out myself: add a simple And type='deposit' after the Where() before the group by date

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE,
   Ifnull(Sum(transactions.deposit_amount),
   0) AS total_deposits,
   type  
FROM
   transactions         
RIGHT JOIN
   calendar                 
      ON (
         Date(transactions.created_at) = calendar.datefield 
      )  
WHERE
   (
      calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT
         Min(Date(created_at))                                       
      FROM
         transactions) AND                                             (
         SELECT
            Max(Date(created_at                                                         ))                                              
         FROM
            transactions
      ) 
   )         
   AND type = 'Deposit'  
GROUP  BY
   date
```

Comment: Assuming type comes from the transaction table, you should add this check to the join condition instead of the where clause. Referencing a column from the transaction table in the where clause will force the join to behave like an inner join.